# Suppresing "Redefining built-in ..." pylint warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

When using Python2/3 [compatibility](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#byte-string-literals) imports, such as

```
from builtins import bytes
```

pylint issues warnings:

> Redefining built-in '`bytes`' (redefined-builtin)

How to suppress them for the `builtins` module?

Answer (score 2):

Since pylint 1.6 there is a new option [`--redefining-builtins-modules`](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/whatsnew/1.6.html#new-features). Adding `builtins` to its default value `six.moves,future.builtins` fixes the problem:

```
# List of qualified module names which can have objects that can redefine
# builtins.
redefining-builtins-modules=six.moves,future.builtins,builtins
```